# bluetoothd or bluetoothctl?

Tags: bluetooth

I have been experimenting with the Bluetooth capability's of the pi and i came across two commands `bluetoothd` and `bluetoothctl`.

When i run `bluetoothd` i get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothd
D-Bus setup failed: Connection ":1.34" is not allowed to own the service     
"org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo bluetoothd
D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
```

But when i run `bluetoothctl` i get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothctl 
[NEW] Controller B8:27:EB:52:E8:AB raspberrypi [default]
[NEW] Device 00:1D:43:C0:15:D0 Coda Pop
[NEW] Device CC:6D:A0:EB:B6:24 Roku Player
[NEW] Device A4:77:33:3E:10:8F A4-77-33-3E-10-8F
[bluetooth]#
```

First: what is the difference between these commands?

Second:why does `bluetoothd` not work?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and my understanding is also shallow. However, `bluetoothd` is the Bluetooth daemon. That's why you can do `systemctl status bluetoothd`. `bluetoothctl` is the primary control tool for Bluetooth devices.

Comment: When you do `systemctl status bluetooth`, does your `bluetooth.service` also show as failed? Mine does, but given your different devices connected, I'm assuming that's not the case for you.

Comment: `man bluetoothd`, `man bluetoothctl`, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193815/271585 (this is not RPi specific)

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

This error means that bluetoothd (the daemon/process) is already running. You can use bluetoothctl (the controller/manager) to connect to a BLE device as normal!
:-)

### Explanation

Hey there. Also a student of bluetooth here. From my understanding (and from ZX9's comment)...

bluetoothd is called a daemon, or a background process. It is inextricably linked to bluetooth services. bluetoothctl is the main controller/manager, who knows how to use this daemon and these bluetooth services. bluetoothctl exposes human-readable methods and data, which is why we mainly interface with the bluetoothctl. The error "D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use" means that bluetooth is already working just fine! :-)

You can see this by `pstree` which shows a graphical hierarchy of your daemons like below:

```
systemd─┬─avahi-daemon───avahi-daemon
        ├─bluetoothd
        ├─cron
        ├─dbus-daemon
        ├─dhcpcd
        ├─hciattach
        ...
```

Now that we know the bluetooth daemon is running, we can connect to a BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) device through `bluetoothctl`. I do not mess with BR/EDR (Classic Bluetooth), but if would appreciate if someone can comment if that works, too!

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller B8:27:EB:DD:65:21 Discovering: yes
[CHG] Device 34:15:13:87:98:37 RSSI: -61
...
[bluetooth]# connect 34:15:13:87:98:37
Attempting to connect to 34:15:13:87:98:37
[CHG] Device 34:15:13:87:98:37 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[NEW] Primary Service
...
[NEW] Characteristic
...
```

### What happens if bluetoothd is NOT running?

bluetooth services come to a halt, and so does bluetoothctl. Let me first identify my that bluetooth daemon PID = 3614. This PID (process ID, maybe?) will, most likely, be different on your machine.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps aux |grep bluetooth
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      3614  0.0  0.9   7176  4096 ?        Ss   01:22   0:00 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd
pi        3842  0.0  0.4   4364  1908 pts/0    S+   01:37   0:00 grep --color=auto bluetooth
```

Now kill it with either `sudo kill 3614` or `sudo systemctl stop bluetooth`. Prove to yourself it is dead by `pstree`

```
systemd─┬─avahi-daemon───avahi-daemon
        ├─cron
        ├─dbus-daemon
        ├─dhcpcd
        ├─hciattach
        ...
```

See that you cannot connect back to bluetoothctl. The command line hangs at

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothctl
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...
```

So you have to ctrl+C out. If you want to restart bluetoothd, we are actually not going to call the command sudo bluetoothd. I'm not sure what this accomplishes besides making command line hang. Use `sudo bluetooth -d` for debugging information if you are curious, but I could not see it doing anything useful for the current question.

To restart bluetoothd, use `sudo systemctl start bluetooth` or `sudo service bluetooth start` . To confirm that it's back, you can use `pstree` , or just bluetoothctl to connect to your devices.